# How to strip label from range vector?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have Alerts gauge, which contains event data that is sampled in random intervals (can have 0 to any amount of events per scrape)

```
Alerts{type="a","hour"="20"} 10
Alerts{type="a","hour"="21"} 20
Alerts{type="b","hour"="21"} 40
```

I want to get latest by type, where hour label will be stripped, so what query would return me following?

```
Alerts{type="a"} 20
Alerts{type="b"} 40
```

i want something like

```
last without(hour)(Alerts)
last_over_time without(hour)(Alerts[24h])
last_over_time(ignoring(hour)Alerts[24h])
last_over_time(label_replace(Alerts, "hour", "", "hour", ".*")[24h:5s])
```

All of this not working...

How can I disable `hour` label, when taking last one only by `type`? Its most common charting task (fill gaps where no events happened), when you are dealing with events, cant find any information on that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
max without (hour) (last_over_time(ALERTS[24h]))
```

Comment: i cannot use max, it will not show latest. avg is close to that, but avg is not what i need - i want last.

Comment: Have you tried the answer? The "max" function is used just to enable the use of the "without (hour)" option. You can use "avg", "sum", or whatever function you want, the result will be the same (you'll see the last value only). It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Basically I need last without hour. Once data leaves outside `last_over_time` function it becomes irrelevant. So i need to make `last_over_time` work as if ALERTS totally lack hours label, so it should select last from timerange by labels, but ignoring one label

Comment: Imagine we have not 10, 20, 40. but  20,10,40. so last will return all 3 values (the data is broken now) and max will show first and third element, despite latest without hour should return second and third.. neither max, min, avg, sum - nothing will work

Comment: and btw its not related to alertmanager in any way, we dont use it, its unusable poorly designed product as prometheus seems to be, but sadly we have to support it. I have custom written event data producer, its a pure prometheus query issue that is does not supports `last` aggregation type. simpliest way is to drop label from producer side